# How to select efficiently by list of dateranges?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-15

I have two tables:

```
create table foo(
  id serial primary key,
  ts timestamp
);

create table bar(
  id serial primary key,
  ts_start timestamp,
  ts_end timestamp
);
```

I need to select all rows from `foo` in which `ts` lies between `bar.ts_start` and `bar.ts_end`. My initial try:

```
SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.ts BETWEEN bar.start AND bar.end;
```

The problem is that table `foo` has 1-3 millions of rows. And despite the fact that I only need to join them with quite small amount of rows from `bar` (30-100), it still performs poorly (6-20s) if I need to add a few more conditions on `foo` (simple equality conditions).

Is there a way or approach to optimize this query?
I expect nested loops in the query plan to be a problem, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Please update your question to include the indexes on both tables and an `Explain Analyze` on the query - all as text, **no images** Also maintain the indentation of the explain plan by bounding it between lines containing only ```,

Comment: All (distinct **?**) rows from `foo` in which `ts` lies between (any **?**) `bar.ts_start` and `bar.ts_end`? Are there any indexes, yet, that might be applicable? Are ranges in `bar` mutually exclusive? Is the number of qualifying rows in `foo` relatively small? What other *"simple equality conditions"* are there, exactly? Which columns need to be in the result, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ranges in table `bar` are mutually exclusive, and their bounds inclusive, your query is as good as it gets.

You need a basic B-tree index on `foo(ts)`, as a bare minimum:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo (ts);
```

Depending on undisclosed information, we might be able to optimize index and query (a lot) more.